# Effective Bandwidth in Cuda

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, gpu-shared-memory

In computing effective bandwidth in Cuda, do I count the number of reads/write in a shared memory. An example code is given below.

```
__global__ void kernel(float *a, float * b, float * c, int num){
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    __shared__ a_shared[NUM];
    __shared__ b_shared[NUM];
    if (i < NUM){
       a_shared[i] = a[i];
       b_shared[i] = b[i]   
       c[i] = a_shared[i] + b_shared[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#performance-metrics . This is documented in section 8.2.2 of tthe nvidia documnetation

Comment: A careful read of that section suggests to me that global loads/stores are in view, where the backing store for the global traffic is DRAM.  Therefore shared activity is not in view and should not be included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With respect to [the section](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#bandwidth) of the best practices guide that you indicate in the comments above, I would say the answer is no, shared traffic should not be included.

How do we know this?

1. A principal purpose of the calculation of effective bandwidth is to compare it to theoretical bandwidth:

> To measure performance accurately, it is useful to calculate theoretical and effective bandwidth. When the latter is much lower than the former, design or implementation details are likely to reduce bandwidth, and it should be the primary goal of subsequent optimization efforts to increase it.

However the theoretical bandwidth calculation only includes global memory traffic to the DRAM:

> Using these data items, the peak theoretical memory bandwidth of the NVIDIA Tesla M2090 is 177.6 GB/s:

That number is a DRAM bandwidth.  It does not include shared memory bandwidth.

2. The references for profiler measurements all pertain to global memory traffic, not shared memory:

> Requested Global Load Throughput
>
> Requested Global Store Throughput
>
> Global Load Throughput
>
> Global Store Throughput
>
> DRAM Read Throughput
>
> DRAM Write Throughput

3. The method for calculating theoretical shared memory bandwidth is not documented anywhere that I am aware of in CUDA formal documentation, so it could not be included in a theoretical bandwidth calculation.  Therefore including measurement of shared memory bandwidth would not make sense for comparison purposes.